# Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Tags: vue.js

Знаю что вопрос дубликат.. и такое можно нагуглить.. Но когда я возвращаюсь к своему тестовому коду - я понимаю что я нифига не понимаю. Переспрашиваю конкретно для своего случая

Собственно ошибка в консоли:

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "amount"`

Выводится когда нажимаю `+` и изменяется amount только в компоненте

```js
  Vue.component('product-item', {
        // camelCase в JavaScript
        props: ['id', 'name', 'price', 'imgSrc', 'amount'],
        template: '<div class="product-item" >\n' +
            '        <header class="product-header">{{ name }}</header>\n' +
            '        <img class="product-img"\n' +
            '             src="https://d10qoa1dy3vloz.cloudfront.net/slots-img/zoe/zoe111_zoeva_144softconcealerbrush_1_1560x1960-41kpd.jpg"\n' +
            '             alt="">\n' +
            '        <div class="product-info">\n' +
            '            <div class="flex-end">\n' +
            '                <div class="price product-price">${{ price }}</div>\n' +
            '            </div>\n' +
            '            {{ amount }}\n' +
            '            <div class="text-center">\n' +
            '                <button v-on:click="deductOne">-</button>\n' +
            '                <input class="prod-amount" v-on:input="validateAmount" type="number" v-model="amount" value="0">\n' +
            '                <button v-on:click="addOne">+</button>\n' +
            '            </div>\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '    </div>',

        data: function () {
            return {
                newAmount: this.amount
            }
        },

        methods: {
            addOne: function () {
                this.validateAmount();
                this.amount += 1;
            },
            deductOne: function () {
                this.validateAmount();
                this.amount = (this.amount)
                    ? this.amount - 1
                    : 0;
            },
            validateAmount: function () {
                this.amount = Math.abs(this.amount | 0);
            },
        }
    });


    const someProducts = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'brush',
            price: '2.40',
            imgSrc: "https://d10qoa1dy3vloz.cloudfront.net/slots-img/zoe/zoe111_zoeva_144softconcealerbrush_1_1560x1960-41kpd.jpg",
            amount: 0,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'super brush',
            price: '4.80',
            imgSrc: "https://d10qoa1dy3vloz.cloudfront.net/slots-img/zoe/zoe111_zoeva_144softconcealerbrush_1_1560x1960-41kpd.jpg",
            amount: 0,
        }
    ];

    const vueProducts = new Vue({
        el: '#products',
        data: {
            products: someProducts,
        },
    });
```

```css
  .text-center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .bucket {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .flex-end {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .flex-space-between {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .flex-wrap {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .product-item {

        background: antiquewhite;
        border: 4px solid white;
        width: 200px;
        height: 350px;
    }

    .product-header {
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .product-img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .price {
        font-family: monospace;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: forestgreen;
    }

    .product-info {
        padding: 4px;
    }

    .product-price {
        min-width: 70px;
    }

    .prod-amount {
        max-width: 70px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="site-header flex-space-between">
    <div class="logo">
        My Shop
    </div>
    <div class="user-settings">register</div>
</div>


<div class="menu flex-space-between">
    <h1>my menu gg</h1>
    <div class="bucket">
        Items added:
        <div class="bucket-count">0</div>
        <div class="price bucket-price">$2.30</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="products" class="flex-wrap">
    <product-item v-for="product in products"
        v-bind:id="product.id"
        v-bind:name="product.name"
        v-bind:price="product.price"
        v-bind:imgSrc="product.imgSrc"
        v-bind:amount="product.amount"
    ></product-item>
</div>
```

P.S. Извините за большой кусок говнокода. Я первый раз пробую `Vue`
P.S.S. Другие замечания приму тоже

Comment: Вы передали свойство `amount` дочернему компоненту, а потом делаете подобные вещи `this.amount += 1;`, а это запрещено. Создайте другое свойство на основе этого и манипулируйте им.

Comment: @doigrales "Создайте другое свойство на основе этого и манипулируйте им" - я не понимаю. Я первый раз vue открыл

Comment: Ну в вашем примере уже есть свойство `newAmount`, ну и манипулируйте им `this.newAmount+= 1;` вместо `this.amount += 1;`. Если такой вариант не подходит и вам нужно менять именно свойство родителя, а именно `v-bind:amount="product.amount"`, то вам помогут [события](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: Как вариант, можно забиндить весь объект: `v-bind:product="product"`, таким образом, будет передаваться объект, по ссылке, и дочка будет напрямую влиять на родителя. Конечно, это не по фен-шую Vuejs: поток данных в одну сторону родитель => дочка, а назад - через события. Но это вам решать... Кстати, можно биндить сразу кучу: `v-bind="{id: product.id, name: product.name}"`

Comment: "в одну сторону родитель => дочка, а назад - через события." Можно подробней пожалуйста?